# How to compare previous context with current context in React 16.x?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to compare previous context value with the current context value in the consumer child component's lifecycle methods?

If there is no way to do that, is there any other workaround or an alternate solution to this?

FYI: I'm using react v16.8.1

Answer (score 4):

**Using HOC:**

```
const withContext = Wrapped => props => (
    <SomeContext.Consumer>
        {value => <Wrapped {...props} contextValue={value}/>}
    </SomeContext.Consumer>
);

const MyComponent = withContext(class extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.contextValue !== this.props.contextValue) {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

**Using hooks:**

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    ...
    const contextValue = useContext(SomeContext);
    const [oldContextValue, saveContextValue] = useState(contextValue);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(oldContextValue, contextValue);
        saveContextValue(contextValue);
    }, [contextValue]);
    ...
}
```

Note that `useEffect` runs only on the first render and when `contextValue` changes. So if you don't really need old `contextValue` for something, you don't need `useState`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you're going to have dynamic context its value will most likely come from a state of a parent component. 
So why not detect changes in the state instead of trying to detect changes in the Provider?

Like in the example for dynamic context in the react documentation : https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#dynamic-context